# In Pine Script, we note that CloseSig changes with the change of timeCross. I want to keep value CloseSig even if it changes timeCross

Tags: pine-script

In Pine Script, we note that `CloseSig` changes with the change of `timeCross`. I want to keep value `CloseSig` even if it changes `timeCross`.

My code is below:

```
//@version=5

indicator("Signal", overlay=true)

var float timeCross = na

var float TimeSig = na

var float CloseSig = na

var float Signal = na

em20 = ta.ema(close, 20)

em50 = ta.ema(close, 50)

CrSignal = ta.crossover(em20, em50)

Signal := CrSignal

if Signal

    timeCross +=1

if timeCross == 1

    TimeSig := ta.valuewhen(Signal, time, 0)
    CloseSig := ta.valuewhen(Signal, close, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYdmV.png)# First understand error

> var float timeCross = na

Here you are trying to increment, but you can't increment `na` so initialize with 0

> var float Signal = na

Here you reassign Boolean value to float that can't possible, So change the type to bool `var bool Signal = naa

### Here is my solution:

```
//@version=5

indicator("Signal", overlay=true, max_labels_count=1)

var float timeCross = 0

var float TimeSig = na

var float CloseSig = 0

var bool Signal = na

em20 = ta.ema(close, 20)

em50 = ta.ema(close, 50)

CrSignal = ta.crossover(em20, em50)

Signal := CrSignal

if Signal
    timeCross +=1

if timeCross == 1
    TimeSig := ta.valuewhen(Signal, time, 0)
    CloseSig := ta.valuewhen(Signal, close, 0)

txt = str.format("Date: {0, date}", TimeSig)

label.new(bar_index, low, str.tostring(CloseSig), style = label.style_label_up)
label.new(bar_index, high, txt, style = label.style_label_down)

plot(em20, color=color.lime)
plot(em50, color=color.red)
plotshape(CrSignal, "", shape.arrowup, location.belowbar, color.red, size=size.huge)
```

Comment: I didn't explain the problem correctly...
The timeCross changes with each condition check. Now I am when the signal number one appears, but when another signal appears, timeCross becomes number two. I can't control the previous signal.

Comment: @Mr.M use array